# proc in Tcl oo::class

Tags: oop, tcl

A silly question. I have a oo::class and make an awful thing - including procs into a constructor and a method:

```
oo::class create MyClass {

    constructor {args} {
        proc silly {args} {
            puts "-------------silly's args: $args"
            puts namespace=[namespace current]
            set v [namespace current]::sillyvar
            puts $v=[incr $v]
            puts vars=[info vars [namespace current]::*]
        }
    }
    destructor {
        foreach proc {silly SILLY} {
            rename $proc ""
        }
    }
    method createprocs {} {
        proc SILLY {args} {
            puts "-------------SILLY's args: $args"
            set v [namespace current]::sillyvar
            puts $v=[incr $v]
        }
    }
    method another {} {
        silly ;# works ok
    }
}
MyClass create myobj
myobj createprocs
[info object namespace myobj]::silly hello world
myobj another
[info object namespace myobj]::SILLY HELLO WORLD
MyClass destroy
```

---

The output looks OK:

```
-------------silly's args: hello world
namespace=::oo::Obj12
::oo::Obj12::sillyvar=1
vars=::oo::Obj12::sillyvar
-------------silly's args: 
namespace=::oo::Obj12
::oo::Obj12::sillyvar=2
vars=::oo::Obj12::sillyvar
-------------SILLY's args: HELLO WORLD
::oo::Obj12::sillyvar=3
```

---

Can you kind folks say, is it correct? And if so, where it can be useful?

What I see just now is:

1) The silly and the SILLY both are 'exported'.

2) I need no "my silly" and "[self] silly" to access the silly proc from an object.

Comment: Might be better to ask this question at [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0):

> Can you kind folks say, is it correct?

It looks OK to me, except that you don't need the destructor. The procedures are created in the object instance's namespace (which is also where the object's variables are, FWIW) and that's automatically deleted when the object is destroyed (and *vice versa* too; you can't have one without the other).

> And if so, where it can be useful?

I use procedures (and other commands) created inside methods and constructors a fair bit. They can do things like acting like a private sub-language of Tcl and so on (just as you can do with putting commands in a normal namespace; it's not significantly different), so that's really quite useful. They're also very easy to delegate to using a `forward`ed method.

One of the easier tricks is to make a sub-object inside an outer object and to delegate some method calls through:

```
oo::class create Outer {
    constructor {} {
        Inner create inner [self]
        puts "created [self]"
    }
    destructor {
        puts "destroyed [self]"
    }
    method foo {} {
        puts "this is foo of [self]"
    }
    forward bar  inner foo
}
oo::class create Inner {
    constructor {outer} {
        puts "created [self] inside $outer"
    }
    destructor {
        puts "destroyed [self]"
    }
    method foo {} {
        puts "this is foo of [self]"
    }
}
```

Demonstrating this:

```
Outer create x
# ⇒ created ::oo::Obj13::inner inside ::x
# ⇒ created ::x
x foo
# ⇒ this is foo of ::x
x bar
# ⇒ this is foo of ::oo::Obj13::inner
x destroy
# ⇒ destroyed ::x
# ⇒ destroyed ::oo::Obj13::inner
```

This shows the containment and delegation at work (which is based on the same mechanism that your procedures would be using). As you can see, `inner` is made inside the private namespace of `x`, and `x bar` is routed through to `inner foo`. Even better, when `x` is destroyed, so is `inner` with no special code at all; that's *very* useful in complex code.

Comment: Of course, you can use `interp alias` to make commands that route to methods of particular objects. The syntax is a touch messy because of the possibility of routing to another interpreter, but it's not too difficult to use.

Comment: And yes, I've got code that has really complex procedures inside methods. It's probably a bit scary though, as it is doing a lot of deeply non-obvious things besides.

Comment: Thank you, Donal, for detailed answer. I was really somewhat perplexed discovering this as the object namespace seems to be a special one. It's good that not for procs that are not redundant in this small namespace of object. E.g. we want to have a code without access to the object variables, i.e. a pure function - inside the object - then an internal proc could help.